# Custom UINavigationItem disappears on pushViewController

Tags: ios5.1

I am running into a weird issue with a custom `UINavigationItem` disappearing when I push a viewcontroller. Here's my setup:

```
RootViewController is UITabController

UITabController
   Tab1->CustomNavController->ViewController1
   Tab2->CustomNavController->ViewController2
   Tab3->CustomNavController->ViewController3
```

I have a custom `UINavigationItem` (with rightBarButtonItems) that I push on to the `CustomNavController` for all the tabs. Everything works fine with the first level view controllers on the tabs.

The problem occurs when I push a new `ViewController` (say VC4) on to a `ViewController` (say `ViewController3`) - either via a segue push or through `pushViewController` with a custom nib.

The custom navigation item disappears and the only way I seem to get it back is to customize the `self.navigationItem` in VC4 - which I don't want to do.

Any ideas and help is greatly appreciated.